# Why is my report showing #Error in my column?

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer

Ok so I have a class that has the following setup.

```
public class Test { 
    private int _TestID;
    private Test1 _MyData;

    public int TestID {
        get { return _TestID; }
        set { _TestID = value; }
    }
    public Test1 MyData {
        get { return _MyData; }
        set { _MyData = value; }
    }
}

public class Test1 {
    private string _TestString;

    public string TestString {
        get { return _TestString; }
        set { _TestString = value; }
    }
}
```

In my report, I have the following value set in one of the Tablix Fields.

```
=Fields!MyData.Value.TestString
```

I feed the report a `List<Test>`. Well my report shows up as #Error in the field. The report was working fine and I am not really sure what has changed.

**Here is a sample report:**

[image: Sample Report]

**EDIT 1**

The data is being retrieved from a WCF service that is hosted on our network. The service loads up all of the data from the database and clients just pull down the list.

So to provide more clarity to my question the report is not being generated from any database query but from the objects themselves.

```
public static void LoadReport() {
    List<Test> allTestData = PublishService.TestClient().GetAllTestData().ToList();
    ReportViewer.Reset();
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TestReport.rdlc";
    ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource();
    datasource.Name = "DataSet1";
    datasource.Value = allTestData;
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: That is just what happens when an `Exception` is thrown.. hard to tell without knowing exactly what you did.

Comment: Is there a way to get the exception? Or find out why it is erroring?

Comment: You could wrap the code in a `try...catch` and print the `Exception.Message` to the cell?

Comment: Perhaps adding a default constructor to your classes may help.

Comment: Hmm, well I feed it a list to the DataSource property. How do you print it out to the cell?

Comment: personally I can't see how anyone can tell what the error is or why it's being generated with that code that you posted.. post the code that applies to what you are doing when you get the error.. `hint` set break points and use the debugger.. how is anyone suppose to know what that code or your code is suppose to do.. ask yourself the same question if one of us were to post such abstract code..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Can you tell me how setting breakpoints and using the debugger is going to help anyone on here? The program isn't throwing any exceptions so I am not really sure what else to provide. I am setting the DataSource and then refreshing the report viewer that's really the only extra code that your not seeing. Maybe someone that is really good with reporting will find the question and be able to help me out. Especially with figuring out how to find the exact error.

Comment: What would really help is knowing how to find what #Error is.

Comment: Well let me say this then.. the report is not self generating so I assuming that you are getting the data from somewhere..for example what is the query used to generate the report..? what is the `Source` of the DataSource give more information.. that is why I asked the question to begin with.. your did not provide that information in your original question .. so please think about what and or how others would ask the question.. if you are feeding a List and Binding the List as a DataSource then perhaps you could show what and how the list is being populated..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added more clarity to the question by showing where the data was coming from.

Comment: just curious instead of using this line `RecruiterReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource` can you just point to the location of the actual .`rdlc` file..? also this line `RecruiterReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);` can you use the `.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", PublishService.TestClient().GetAllTestData().ToList())` what happens if you use the LocalReport Class example on MSDN site can you get it to work using there example but fitting your use case..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Just thought of something.. do you have access to the `report definition file`? if so you need to set what ever fields in the report , where you're seeing the #ERROR to the same field(s) as that of the datasource I hope this may help you..

Comment: Tried all of that and none of that helped. Pretty sure the issue is with the `=Fields!MyData.Value.TestString` and nothing to do with the reports datasource or using a different style of reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooooooo....the problem was that I didn't have Visual Studio Service Pack 1 installed.